# Need help adding content in a value attribute

Tags: html, json

I am using an existing API to preload data in the textarea. The problem that I am running into is that when I have a json object in the data-trix-attachment attribute my HTML code breaks and the browser can't read it because there are double quotes inside single quotes.

If I change the attributes to single quotes than I would have to make my data-trix-attachment json object double quotes which will leave me to the same problem.

This snipped below is generated dynamically so I have very limited access to modfying it. Would anyone have an idea on how I can 
format so that the browser can read it?

```
   <input id="139" value="<div><a data-trix-content-type="image/png"
 data-trix-attachment="{'contentType':'image/png','filename':'Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png','filesize':9291,'height':77,'href':'http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447699983504-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png','url':'http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447699983504-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png','width':305}" href="http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447699983504-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png"><figure class="attachment attachment-preview png"><img src="http://localhost/gu/attachments/2015-11-161447699983504-Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png" height="77" width="305"><figcaption class="caption">Screen Shot 2015-11-16 at 11.36.45 AM.png <span class="size">9.07 KB</span></figcaption></figure></a></div>" type="hidden" name="content"> <trix-editor input="139"></trix-editor>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to replace the inner quotes as HTML literals. This is known as *escaping*.

The HTML literal code for a double quote mark is `&quot;`.

---

Edit: Just to clarify, I mean the second layer of quotes. Your code becomes something like (truncated):

```
<input id="139" value="<div><a data-trix-content-type=&quot;image/png&quot; data-trix-attachment=&quot;{[JSON DATA]}&quot; href=&quot;http://[URL]&quot;></a></div>">
```